# I want to extract up to a specific number of alphanumeric characters from an email preamble

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract up to the first 10 alphanumeric characters (0-9, a-z, A-Z) (exclude all special characters) from email preambles.  The extraction should stop exclusive of the "@".

Examples, How it should function:

```
john@yahoo.com : john
suzieQ87@hotmail.com: suzieQ87
ilikemakingeggseverymorning@gmail.com: ilikemakin
49!Gar.a_ge8UT@aol.com: 49Garage8U
```

I would like to use regex in Google Sheets.

Thanks!

I tried:

```
=regexextract("alwayssa.turning@gmail.com","^.{0,9}[[:alpha:]]") returned: alwayssa.tu
=regexextract("suzie@gmail.com",".{0,9}[\w\s^@]") returned: suzie@gmai
=REGEXEXTRACT("suzie40@gmail.com,".{0,9}[\w\d^\W]") returned: suzie40@gm
```

I can't figure out how to exclude special characters and how to stop at the "@".

Comment: Don’t use a regular expression. Use a split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to skip special symbols, you can do extraction in two steps:

- replace special symbols:
  `REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[^a-zA-Z0-9@]+","")`
- extract up to ten first symbols with regex:
  `[[:alnum:]]{0,10}`

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[^a-zA-Z0-9@]+",""),"[[:alnum:]]{0,10}")
```